# Converting UInt8 C++ values to C# byte array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, type-conversion, marshalling

I have a 1-dimensional C++ array containing `UInt8` values - I would like to convert those values and place them into a 2D C# `byte` array. Currently, my code is giving me incorrect values. Here is my code:

```
IntPtr ptr = GetDataFromCPPSide();    

byte[,] data = new byte[dimension1, dimension2];
for(int i = 0; i < dimension1; i ++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < dimension2; j++)
    {
        data[i, j] = Marshal.ReadByte((IntPtr)(ptr.ToInt64() + j + i * dimension2) * 1));
    }
}
```

Right now this only converts some values correctly. I'm sure it has something to do with the way I'm converting the value in the `for` loop. I've placed a check on the C++ side and the values are being returned properly. Any ideas?

Comment: When you are dealing with byte to something or vice verse transformations *always* consider Encoding. Absence of it is a big red flag.

Comment: @Tigran Could you elaborate?

Comment: You have to use Encoding while converting from one byte stream to data type. Is it Unicode ? Utf-8? Something else ? Not necessary *that* is your problem, but consider that anyway. That's what this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: And a wrong comment at that, binary streams have no notion of encoding. You're confusing strings and byte arrays here. Essentially meaningless noise when you have no idea of the actual issue.

Comment: @Blindy nor byte neither strings have Encoding notion per se. Encoding is a matter of conversion from one state to another. My comment refers to absence of it which is a bad signal.

Comment: @Roka545 if you write same logic in c++,  can you read data properly ?

Comment: @Blindy "My comment refers to absence of it which is a bad signal." That line confuses me. A byte stream can contain all kind of data like numbers. What do you encode numbers with? From how the question was asked I would expect that the first element of the C++ array is different from the first in the C# array (pos 0,0). There is no encoding. I think the more important part might be the conversion from unsigned to signed.

Comment: You don't need to try to explain these things to him, he's obviously set in his wrong views.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
pingdata[i, j] = (byte)Marshal.ReadByte((IntPtr)(ptr.ToInt64() + (i * d2 + j)));
```

fixed the issue.